# How is memory alignment done usually?

Tags: c++, inheritance, memory-alignment

Have a look at these 2 cases:

```
class A {
    public:
    int a;

    A () { a = 10;}
    void foo () {std::cout << "a = " << a << std::endl;}
};
```

Here sizeof(A) gives 4 bytes, which makes sense.

```
class A {
    public:
    int a;

    A () { a = 10;}
    virtual void foo () {std::cout << "a = " << a << std::endl;}
};
```

Here sizeof(A) gives 16 bytes as opposed to 12 bytes (4 + 8 for pointer).

Is there any explanation in terms of memory alignment for this ?

Comment: virtual is expensive and should be used carefully.

Comment: Yes, but why not 12 bytes ?

Comment: @shrinidhisondur probably because of padding.

Comment: Why wouldn't it do it for 4 though ?

Comment: @shrinidhisondur: Because a 4 byte `int` is happy sitting on a 4 byte boundary.  An 8 byte pointer, on the other hand, wants an 8 byte boundary of its own.  As Tony points out, in order for the v-table pointer in the second array element to also be on an 8 byte boundary, `sizeof (A)` needs to be a multiple of 8.

Comment: see also [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439240/sizeof-class-with-int-function-virtual-function-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

It's up to the compiler how virtual functions are implemented, but what's likely happening here is it wants/needs to align the 8-byte pointer to the virtual dispatch table on a multiple-of-8 memory address.  Then there's either { 4 bytes `a`, 4 padding, 8 vdt pointer } or { 8 vdt pointer, 4 bytes `a`, 4 padding  } - the latter's less obvious, but consider that arrays of `A` need to be contiguous and spaced per `sizeof(A)`, so 12's rounded up to 16 given the 8-byte alignment.

Answer (score 0):

FIRST in virtual dispatch table, visual functions need a pointer size , in 32 bits computer, the size of pointer is 4 bytes, int 64 bits it's 8 bytes. so I think your computer is 64 bits.

SECOND the sizeof(A) should consider the padding and memory alignment .
so 16 bytes is arranged like that: 4 bytes(int a) + 8 bytes(a virtual function pointer int 64 bits) + 4 bytes padding(because the max size of elements in A is the virtual function pointer which is 8 bytes, so the sizeof(A)should be the integral multiples of 8 bytes )